# When I change the HTML website to Django redirects app, I how do I do a 301 redirection automatically for diverting traffic from an old to a new link?

Tags: django, redirect, sites

**Django redirects app**

I added this , in my installed app section in settings.py

'django.contrib.redirects',

MIDDLEWARE = [

```
'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
```

]

I added the sites in the admin panel

domain name : http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I added redirects in the admin panel.
old link  : redirect from : **/index/**

&
new link : redirect to: **/index.html**

I didn't mention this URL link in my urls.py like  below

**path('index.html/', views.index, name='index'),**

I check the invalid URL as new URL.

I run the local server. its not working